# Failed to load SQLSRV driver on Centos 7.2 using PHP 7.0.7

Tags: php, azure, centos7, php-7, sqlsrv

I just installed a new VM in Azure with Centos 7.2.
On this server I installed httpd using `yum install httpd`

After that I installed PHP 7.0.7 using the following link: https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/

PHP is working fine with no problem at this point.

But then I want to connect to a Azure SQL Database. After searching the forums of stackoverflow I saw that I need a PHP 7 SQLSRV driver.

I got the driver from this link: https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/tree/PHP-7.0-Linux/CentOS7

To load the driver I copied the file to the following path: `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`

And updated the php.ini with the following line `extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_sqlsrv_7_ts.so`

I did this because I was not sure if the driver is automatically loaded when placed in the modules folder. Does it load automatically?

After that I created a test.php file with the following code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

echo php_ini_loaded_file(); 
$connectionInfo = array("pwd" => "PASSWORD", $serverName = "tcp:SERVER_URL:1443"); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />"; } 
else {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
}
```

The code above gives me the following error:

```
/etc/php.ini 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /var/www/website/test.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/website/test.php on line 9
```

Does the PHP SQLSRV driver file needs to be written down in the phpinfo? Because I don't see it there.

Could someone help me out? If you need more information please ask and I will provide it.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**

When I run `php -v` on the server i get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_sqlsrv_7_ts.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_sqlsrv_7_ts.so: undefined symbol: SQLGetDiagField in Unknown on line 0 PHP 7.0.7 (cli) (built: May 28 2016 07:53:22) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed unixODBC and the Microsoft ODBC Driver? You should start for there *before* copying the PHP extensions.

To asure you have correctly installed the unixODBC Driver Manager you could execute:

> odbcinst -j

And to assure the second one you could execute:

> odbcinst -q -d -n

and look for "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server".

Here is an extensive guide to all the necesaries step's for connecting to a SQL Database from PHP -> [MS PHP SQL Linux Tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/blob/PHP-7.0-Linux/LinuxTutorial.md)

P.D.: NO, the PHP extensions doesn't load automatically, you have to "call" them from a php.ini in the extension=extension.so form.